# Difference between pairs of singlet on different sites

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter

I am working on a problem where I have sites numbered: 1,2,3,4. Each of which could support up to two electrons. I am currently looking at the case where there is four electrons, one on each site. Calling
$$|s_{ij}\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|\uparrow\rangle_i|\downarrow\rangle_j-|\downarrow\rangle_i|\uparrow\rangle_j)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(c_{i\uparrow}^\dagger c_{j\downarrow}^\dagger-c_{i\downarrow}^\dagger c_{j\uparrow}^\dagger)|0\rangle$$ to be the singlet state between an electron on site i and site j:
Is there any difference between the states

$$|\psi\rangle = |s_{12}\rangle |s_{34} \rangle$$ and
$$|\phi\rangle = |s_{13}\rangle |s_{24} \rangle$$

My intuition tells me they might be the same since they are the same states up to a minus sign, since $|\phi\rangle$ is just $|\psi\rangle$ with site 2 and 3 permuted. However at the same time, for $|\psi\rangle$, the spin of electrons on site 1 and 2 are anticorrelated, while for $|\phi\rangle$, the spin of electron on site 1 and 3 are anticorrelated.